# MongoDB executionStats understanding

Tags: mongodb

I am currently trying to integrate indexes in one of my collection. All of my tests worked and I can really see the improvments (number of scanned document etc) however one of my result is a bit weird (or maybe I did not understand it well).
Could you please explain me?

I have a collection of owner/holder/product (here is an example and by the same the concerned document):

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("59ef7c84f545c8278c8cd967"),
    "owner": "59ef7c83f545c8278c8cd965",
    "holder": "59ef7c84f545c8278c8cd967",
    "product": 1,
    "date" : ISODate("2017-10-24T17:46:44.367Z")
}
```

Here are the indexes:

```
{
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
                "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "mydb.relation"
},
{
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
                "owner" : 1
        },
        "name" : "onlyOwner",
        "ns" : "mydb.relation"
},
{
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
                "holder" : 1
        },
        "name" : "onlyHolder",
        "ns" : "mydb.relation"
},
{
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
                "owner" : 1,
                "holder" : 1
        },
        "name" : "ownerAndHolder",
        "ns" : "mydb.relation"
},
{
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
                "owner" : 1,
                "product" : 1
        },
        "name" : "ownerAndProduct",
        "ns" : "mydb.relation"
}
```

I executed the following query:

```
db.relation.find({ $and : [{"owner" : "59ef7c83f545c8278c8cd965"}, {"holder" : "59ef7c84f545c8278c8cd967"}]})
```

And my relation is well returned (the one mentionned earlier). So I decided to check executionStats to see the status and here is the result:

```
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "mydb.relation",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                                {
                                        "holder" : {
                                                "$eq" : "59ef7c84f545c8278c8cd967"
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "owner" : {
                                                "$eq" : "59ef7c83f545c8278c8cd965"
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                                "holder" : {
                                        "$eq" : "59ef7c84f545c8278c8cd967"
                                }
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                        "owner" : 1,
                                        "product" : 1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "ownerAndProduct",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                        "owner" : [ ],
                                        "product" : [ ]
                                },
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : false,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 1,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "owner" : [
                                                "[\"59ef7c83f545c8278c8cd965\", \"59ef7c83f545c8278c8cd965\"]"
                                        ],
                                        "product" : [
                                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                        ]
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [
                        {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "owner" : 1,
                                                "holder" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "ownerAndHolder",
                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                "owner" : [ ],
                                                "holder" : [ ]
                                        },
                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "owner" : [
                                                        "[\"59ef7c83f545c8278c8cd965\", \"59ef7c83f545c8278c8cd
                                                ],
                                                "holder" : [
                                                        "[\"59ef7c84f545c8278c8cd967\", \"59ef7c84f545c8278c8cd
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        },
                        {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "filter" : {
                                        "holder" : {
                                                "$eq" : "59ef7c84f545c8278c8cd967"
                                        }
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "owner" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "onlyOwner",
                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                "owner" : [ ]
                                        },
                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "owner" : [
                                                        "[\"59ef7c83f545c8278c8cd965\", \"59ef7c83f545c8278c8cd
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        },
                        {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "filter" : {
                                        "owner" : {
                                                "$eq" : "59ef7c83f545c8278c8cd965"
                                        }
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "holder" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "onlyHolder",
                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                "holder" : [ ]
                                        },
                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "holder" : [
                                                        "[\"59ef7c84f545c8278c8cd967\", \"59ef7c84f545c8278c8cd
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 1,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 1,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 1,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                                "holder" : {
                                        "$eq" : "59ef7c84f545c8278c8cd967"
                                }
                        },
                        "nReturned" : 1,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 3,
                        "advanced" : 1,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 0,
                        "restoreState" : 0,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "docsExamined" : 1,
                        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "nReturned" : 1,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                                "works" : 2,
                                "advanced" : 1,
                                "needTime" : 0,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 0,
                                "restoreState" : 0,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                        "owner" : 1,
                                        "product" : 1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "ownerAndProduct",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                        "owner" : [ ],
                                        "product" : [ ]
                                },
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : false,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 1,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "owner" : [
                                                "[\"59ef7c83f545c8278c8cd965\", \"59ef7c83f545c8278c8cd965\"]"
                                        ],
                                        "product" : [
                                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                        ]
                                },
                                "keysExamined" : 1,
                                "seeks" : 1,
                                "dupsTested" : 0,
                                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                "seenInvalidated" : 0
                        }
                }
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "NCEL15605",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "3.4.6",
                "gitVersion" : "c55eb86ef46ee7aede3b1e2a5d184a7df4bfb5b5"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

So I understand that onlyHolder onlyOwner are rejected but I don't understand why ownerAndHolder is rejected and ownerAndProduct is used as I am not using it as variable.

Can someone help me to understand this result (the response is correct from the find, however this is the choice of MongoDB I did not understand) ?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at these two fields:

```
"nReturned" : 1,
"totalDocsExamined" : 1,
```

It means that Mongo had to examine only one document to return one. Then the chosen query plan, although counter-intuitively, achieved the best result possible. It looks like at least one other plan could have achieved the same result (the owner holder index). In such cases Mongo is free to choose a plan.

If you want to know the details of query optimizations read this [material](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/#read-operations-query-optimization).